# Jena/ARQ: Difference between Model, Graph and DataSet

Tags: java, jena

I'm starting to work with the Jena Engine and I think I got a grasp of what semantics are.
However I'm having a hard time understanding the different ways to represent a bunch of triples in Jena and ARQ:

- The first thing you stumble upon when starting is `Model` and the documentation says its Jenas name for RDF graphs.
- However there is also `Graph` which seemed to be the necessary tool when I want to query a union of models, however it does not seem to share a common interface with `Model`, although one can get the `Graph` out of a `Model`
- Then there is `DataSet` in ARQ, which also seems to be a collection of triples of some sort.

Sure, afer some looking around in the API, I found ways to somehow convert from one into another. However I suspect there is more to it than 3 different interfaces for the same thing.

So, question is: What are the key design differences between these three? When should I use which one ? Especially: When I want to hold individual bunches of triples but query them as one big bunch (union), which of these datastructures should I use (and why)?
Also, do I "loose" anything when "converting" from one into another (e.g. does `model.getGraph()` contain less information in some way than `model`)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Jena is divided into an API, for application developers, and an SPI for systems developers, such as people making storage engines, reasoners etc.

`DataSet`, `Model`, `Statement`, `Resource` and `Literal` are API interfaces and provide many conveniences for application developers.

`DataSetGraph`, `Graph`, `Triple`, `Node` are SPI interfaces. They're pretty spartan and simple to implement (as you'd hope if you've got to implement the things).

The wide variety of API operations all resolve down to SPI calls. To give an example the [`Model` interface](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) has four different `contains` methods. Internally each results in a call:

```
Graph#contains(Node, Node, Node)
```

such as

```
graph.contains(nodeS, nodeP, nodeO); // model.contains(s, p, o) or model.contains(statement)
graph.contains(nodeS, nodeP, Node.ANY); // model.contains(s, p)
```

Concerning your question about losing information, with `Model` and `Graph` you don't (as far as I recall). The more interesting case is `Resource` versus `Node`. `Resources` know which model they belong to, so you can (in the api) write `resource.addProperty(...)` which becomes a `Graph#add` eventually. `Node` has no such convenience, and is not associated with a particular `Graph`. Hence `Resource#asNode` is lossy.

Finally:

> When I want to hold individual bunches of triples but query them as one big bunch (union), which of these datastructures should I use (and why)?

You're clearly a normal user, so you want the API. You want to store triples, so use `Model`. Now you want to query the models as one union: You could:

- `Model#union()` everything, which will copy all the triples into a new model.
- `ModelFactory.createUnion()` everything, which will create a dynamic union (i.e. no copying).
- Store your models as named models in a TDB or SDB dataset store, and use the `unionDefaultGraph` option.

The last of these works best for large numbers of models, and large model, but is a little more involved to set up.

Comment: That clarified a lot, also I seem to have overlooked ModelFactory.createUnion() up to now, thanks :)

Comment: A little bit more about this distinction: http://willware.blogspot.com/2010/02/jena-node-versus-rdfnode.html

Comment: Also worth noting that neither Triple nor Node (or Quad) are actual interfaces, but classes.

Answer (score 21):

Short answer: `Model` is just a stateless wrapper with lots of convenience methods around a `Graph`. `ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(Graph)` wraps a graph in a model. `Model.getGraph()` gets the wrapped graph.

Most application programmers would use `Model`. Personally I prefer to use `Graph` because it's simpler. I have trouble remembering all the cruft on the `Model` class.

`Dataset` is a collection of several `Model`s: one “default model” and zero or more “named models”. This corresponds to the notion of an “RDF dataset” in SPARQL. (Technically speaking, SPARQL is not a query language for “RDF graphs” but for “RDF datasets” which can be collections of named RDF graphs plus a default graph.)